What are the specific functions within the microcontroller? about memory and serial port
I have some questions regarding microcontrollers. In the case of EPROM and EEPROM memories and Flash memories, it says that it is a non-volatile memory that does not erase the programming, but this programming is what you recorded on the microcontroller or the internal library or both.
The serial port has the following explanation: Serial communication port, used to exchange data with other devices, such as a computer or another microcontroller.
I didn't quite understand the explanation.


Can you elaborate which parts of the explanations you do understand and which you don't? What do you think might be meant?

Non-volatile means the programming isn't lost when power is removed from the device.
An EPROM is an Erasable Programmable Read Only Memory. It can be programmed, and then erased, usually by exposing it to ultraviolet light through a quartz window in the chip, and then reprogrammed. The device retains its programming whether it is powered or not.
An EEPROM is similar, but it is Electronically Erasable, which means it can be erased in circuit through the pins, you don't need UV light to do it.
FLASH memory is a type of EEPROM that is faster and whose data is typically accessed in large blocks.
Serial communication is a means of communicating between electronic devises with the data sent a bit at a time as opposed to parallel communications where data is usually sent a byte at a time. A serial communications port has the advantage of using fewer physical connections (wires, circuit traces) between devices, but is typically slower than parallel communications.

In the eeprom I understood that you can erase it with ultraviolet but does that mean that it can only be written (recorded) once?
In the case of the serial port, I have difficulty understanding it because it is a very generic port, as far as I can understand, it can also be anything like port A or port B.
I would need to understand in a practical way what this port really is because for me this type of port is only used as a printer (old connection)

@LUFER  EEPROM is not erased with ultraviolet, EPROM is. They can be written many times, that's the whole point of being able to erase them. One that can only be written once is called a PROM. A serial port is just a port that transfers data one bit at a time, so if you have an 8 bit byte to send it would transfer 1 bit, then the next, then the next, until all 8 were sent. How exactly that is done depends on what protocol the port uses.

By saying non-volatile it means the data in this area stays even on a power loss. On the other hand in volatile memories like RAMs, your data will be removed on power loss. So, your program (whole program; all your libraries, middlewares and main program) written to this non-volatile area and stays there (If you not change standard configuration while loading your program to the device.). CPU boots up from some specific address at this area and runs your program.
Serial communication is a type of communication used to communicate with other devices. Serial communication works serially, as the name suggests. In other words, the data you give to this unit is broken down in the relevant hardware and sent to other devices in the form of bits. These other devices can be other processors or different devices using the same physical infrastructure. There are many different types of serial communication. Here are a few of the most common ones: UART/USART, SPI, I2C, 1-Wire, etc.
